# htaccess: allow own domain request and some specific referers

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, referer

using an .htaccess file i'm trying to allow specific referers and my own domain requests to be processed and deny any others, by redirecting anyway.

Can´t get it work using this .htacces...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.myowndomain\.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.myfrienddomain\.com/subfolder(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.go-out-of-here.com[R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What i try to mean:
If it is not a request from my own domain and it is not a request from my friend's domain...go out of here,
else... passthrough.
Seem to allow from my friends domain but not inner requests, from my own domain.

What's wrong here, friends?? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is called true friendship!

Comment: stackoverflow has save my life more times than many of real best friends, anubhava! ;)
Any ideas about the problem with my .htaccess?

Comment: Most likely Apache is not seeing request coming from your domain as referrer. Are you using localhost or intranet to access this site?

Comment: No. Using real path on internet; :|

Comment: Just use: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !myowndomain [NC]` condition.

Comment: That works, man! Sincerely, don't know why, don't know where is the real difference... the mistake in original rules, but thanks. :D